# WPF C#. Отображение много строчного текста в TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf

Здравствуйте, необходимо вывести в контрол для отображения текста много строчный текст.
Приложение MVVM поэтому осуществляется Binding на длинную строку примерного вида:

"Январь,1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10,11,12,14,15,16,17,18,19,21,31:Февраль,11,12,13,14,15,16,18,19,20,21,22,23,25,26,27,28,29,30,31"

Байндинг осуществляется напрямую на такую строку. Необходимо разбить ее на строки по месяцам
1 строка: "Январь,1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10,11,12,14,15,16,17,18,19,21,31"
2 строка: "Февраль,11,12,13,14,15,16,18,19,20,21,22,23,25,26,27,28,29,30,31"
...

и отобразить в таком виде.

Подскажите какой контрол лучше использовать, как разбить на строки, и можно ли обойтись без конвертора при байндинге (например через FormatString)?

Comment: А почему бы всё-таки не использовать конвертор?

Comment: Пусть будет конвертор, в нем я разобью строку на несколько строк, дальше куда их отображать и как настроить контрол? Можно пример).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант с конвертером:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(string), typeof(string))]
public class MultiLineConverter : IValueConverter {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        return value?.ToString().Replace(':', '\n');
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        return value?.ToString().Replace('\n', ':');
    }
}
```

В XAML:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <settings:MultiLineConverter x:Key="MultiLineConverter" />
</ResourceDictionary>

<TextBlock Text="{Binding Value, Converter={StaticResource MultiLineConverter}}" />
```

Если вдруг нужен TextBox (вроде в вопросе «для отображения текста», но в заголовке TextBox), благодаря `ConvertBack()` будет работать без проблем, при редактировании конвертируя переносы обратно в двоеточия:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding TempValue, Converter={StaticResource MultiLineConverter}}" AcceptsReturn="True" />
```

[image: Пример]

Comment: Я бы всё же заменил на `(value as string)?.Replace(...`.

Comment: @Vlad, логично, спасибо. Это я привык к случаям, если будет число или что-нибудь вроде того.

Comment: Или возможно даже просто `((string)value)?.Replace(...`.

Comment: Спасибо ребят!!!